# unable to send message to qmaster using port 6444 on host "*******": got send error. Exiting

Tags: kaldi

error: commlib error: got select error (Connection refused)
Unable to run job: unable to send message to qmaster using port 6444 on host "naveen": got send error.
Exiting.

queue.pl: It looks like the queue master may be inaccessible.  Trying again after 20 seconts
Error: log file /home/ambertag/kaldi/egs/vystadial_en/s5/exp/make_mfcc/train/q/make_mfcc_train.log does not specify the SGE job-id. at /home/ambertag/kaldi/egs/vystadial_en/s5/utils/queue.pl line 461.

I'm getting this error please get me solution for this answer.